# asp.net core, Any library to get distance and time travel between two locations

Tags: asp.net-core, location, distance

Is there any library that get distance and time travel between two locations with options like: Legs, Vehicle, Bikes ...

I don't want to use  google maps because I have to call an api on their server.

any help please

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I want more details, If can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found this library, It's easy to use

https://docs.mapbox.com/api/navigation/map-matching/

you can create an account and get a key then call an API url to get distance, duration, Like this:

https://api.mapbox.com/matching/v5/mapbox/driving/-117.17282,32.71204;-117.17288,32.71225;-117.17293,32.71244;-117.17292,32.71256?approaches=curb;curb;curb;curb&access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoibm92ZXJzbWFwIiwiYSI6ImNreTdwc3ppNTE3dzkyb3B2MnVzNXpueTUifQ.csYTL2GKkl99Yqk_TQjr5w

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to use google maps because I have to call an api on their server.

The meaning of this sentence is, do you want to use the map offline?

If yes, you can search with keywords `offline map C#`, something like [`osmsharp`](https://github.com/OsmSharp), it need your download map data, and you can use search it by sdk.

If not, [bing maps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/) or [azure maps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/azure-maps/) will the better choices. Because official support engineers will give you help, and you also can get more help in stackoverflow.